# Can we use RSpec + Capybara for integration test with feature plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I would like to use RSpec + Capybara for writing plain text integration test(I don't prefer Cucumber in this stack), something like this

```
Feature: Create product   
  Background:
    Given I am on "/products"

  @javascript
  Scenario: create products
    When I click on "New Product"
     And I fill in "Title" with "Test title"
     And I fill in "Description" with "Test description"
     And I fill in "Image url" with "test.gif"
     And I fill in "Price" with "44.50"
     And I click on "Create Product"
    Then I should see "Product was successfully created"
```

When I tried, got error messages

product.feature:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError) Feature: Create product

I think we can fix this issue by adding some configuration on spec_helper and RSpec specific gem which supports this, but i couldn't able to find out proper solution.

Anyone already had similar issues and what could be ideal solution to fix this issue

Comment: That syntax is incorrect if it's just an rspec feature test. Check the example here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec

Comment: That was working fine, but I would like to create integration specs in plain text in feature

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/railsware/rspec-example_steps/blob/master/README.md, but it doesn't allow/address Feature, Background, Scenario